# Poisson equation as a limit of Helmholtz equation

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Assuming I can solve Helmholtz equation:

$$ \nabla^2 \phi(\textbf r) - \kappa^2 \phi(\textbf r) = f(\textbf r), $$

with some given boundary conditions, where $f(\textbf r)$ is some given source. 
If I take a limit of the solution when $\kappa \to 0$ am I always guaranteed to obtain the correct solution of the corresponding Poisson equation

$$ \nabla^2 \phi(\textbf r) = f(\textbf r), $$

assuming the same boundary conditions? 
Are there some contra examples where this would not be the case, e.g. $f$ is constant and we have an infinite volume or something. In other words, is there an example where for some setup we would not have

$$ \phi_{P}(\textbf r) = \lim_{\kappa \to 0}  \phi_{H}(\textbf r)? $$

Answer (score 3):

Let $\kappa_n\to 0$ and let $\phi_n $ denote the coreresponding solutions. Furthermore,  let $\phi $ denote the solution of the Poison equation (assuming it has a unique solution)

For any $ n $ you habe the PDE
$$
\nabla^2(\phi_n-\phi)=\kappa_n \phi_n
$$
Assuming your boundary conditions allow for standard a priori estimates, this shows that 
$$
\|\phi_{n}-\phi\|_{H^1}\leq C \kappa_n \|\phi_n\|_{L^2}
$$ 
and
$$
\|\phi_n\|_{H^1}\leq C\|f\|_{L^2}.
$$
which together shows the desired convergence.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please say a bit more what is meant by "boundary conditions allow for standard a priori estimates"? I'm not sure if all the conditions above apply in the case of e.g. f = constant and infinite volume, or do they?